# Black screen when booting Manjaro on a macbook

Tags: dual-boot, manjaro, macintosh

I have Manjaro installed next to MacOS, it worked just fine until I rebooted it with `systemctl reboot`, now when I try to boot I get a black screen (or red artifacts ocassionally). [I made a video but it's rather uneventful.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFyArGCJGmg) The thing is I don't really know what I can do about it, it's not GRUB but that Apple bootloader, I can't switch to another tty. Is it even solvable or do I need to reinstall?